# Optimization problem: compound clustered keys, flag conditions and index-merge

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, optimization

Three tables:

`product`: with columns: `( a, g, ...a_lot_more... )`

```
a: PK, clustered
g: bit-column
```

`main`: with columns: `( c, f, a, b, ...a_lot_more... )`

```
c: PK, clustered
f: bit-column
(a, b): UQ
```

`lookup` with columns: `( a, b, c, i )`

```
(a, b): PK, clustered
a: FK to product(a)
c: UQ, FK to main(c)
i: bit-column
```

I can't find good indexes for the join:

```
FROM  
    product
  JOIN 
    lookup
      ON  lookup.a = product.a  
  JOIN
    main
      ON  main.c = lookup.c 
WHERE 
      product.g = 1
  AND
      main.f = 1
  AND 
      lookup.i = 1
  AND lookup.b = 17
```

I tried a covering index on `product (g, a, ...)` and it's used but not with spectacular results.

Some combinations of indexes on the `lookup` table produce execution plans with index-merge, with slight efficiency gain over the previous plan.

Is there some obvious combination that I am missing?

Could a re-design of the structure help?

The DBMS is MySQL 5.5 and all tables are using InnoDB.

---

Table sizes:

```
product: 67K   ,  g applied:    64K 

main:   420K   ,  f applied:   190K

lookup:  12M   ,  b,i applied:  67K
```

Comment: Try moving the filter predicates into the joins and see if the optimiser does something sensible with that. I've seen SQL Server's optimiser fail on that before.

Comment: Looks like a Cartesian product because I do not see anything JOINing from the product table. Or did I miss something ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: You are right. I'll correct the query.

Answer (score 3):

This pains me...

I've had to use temp tables with InnoDB before. Load them with filters, create an index, join these temp table.

The problem as I reckon is if that InnoDB only has Nested Join algorithm: the grown-up RDBMS query optimisers have more to use. This is based on trying to run Data Warehouse type loads on InnoDB.

Temp tables drags the overall complexity down the MySQL query optimiser's level...

Comment: Thnx, I'll try that. The number or rows (after the criteria are applied are not that big, 64K, 67K, 190K respectively). Maybe I should try to get rid of one of the three tables (`main`) by denormalizing data into `lookup`?

Comment: @ypercube: denormalising will make rows wider, lower page density = other problems

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Cartesian product. Redo the JOIN Criteria

```
FROM  
    product
  JOIN 
    lookup
      ON  product.a = lookup.a  
  JOIN
    main
      ON  main.c = lookup.c 
WHERE 
      product.g = 1
  AND
      main.f = 1
  AND 
      lookup.i = 1
  AND lookup.b = 17
```

## ALTERNATE SUGGESTION

This may seem unorthodox and probably smells like SQL Anitpattern, but here it goes...

```
FROM  
    product
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM lookup
        WHERE i=1 AND b=17
    ) lookup ON product.a = lookup.a  
JOIN
   main ON main.c = lookup.c 
WHERE 
    product.g = 1 AND main.f = 1
```

I did not move the `product.g = 1` and `main.f = 1` into subqueries because they are bit fields and will just do a table scan at the point. Even if the bit fields were indexes, the Query Optimizer would simply ignore such an index.

Of course, you could change `SELECT * FROM lookup` to `SELECT a FROM lookup` if your SELECT does not need anything from `lookup`

Perhaps involve a,b in the JOIN between lookup and main if this makes sense

```
FROM  
    product
  JOIN 
    lookup
      ON  product.a = lookup.a  
  JOIN
    main
      ON  main.a = lookup.a AND main.b = lookup.b
WHERE 
      product.g = 1
  AND
      main.f = 1
  AND 
      lookup.i = 1
  AND lookup.b = 17
```

or put back c and join on three columns (Index on the three columns in `main` and `lookup`)

```
FROM  
    product
  JOIN 
    lookup
      ON  product.a = lookup.a  
  JOIN
    main
      ON main.a = lookup.a
      AND main.b = lookup.b
      AND main.c = lookup.c
WHERE 
      product.g = 1
  AND
      main.f = 1
  AND 
      lookup.i = 1
  AND lookup.b = 17
```

Comment: Thnx. Different EXPLAIN plan, but similar performance.

Comment: What the cardinality of the `main.f` and `product.g` ??? If the cardinality of `main.f` and `product.g` for the value is 1 is less than 5% of the table rows, an index on `main.f` and `product.g` may be justifiable.

Comment: Never mind, they are indexed already. If the cardinality of `main.f` and `product.g` is 2, you could ditch those indexes.

Comment: Edited the question with table sizes and rows used (after the conditions are applied).

Comment: I updated my question, suggestion JOINing on a,b instead of c. See if that makes a different EXPLAIN plan

Comment: Thnx for the suggestions but the `b` column cannot be used for the join.